# Split home address separated with a comma

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 15 Address that are formatted like, `1111 Really Cool Street, Sweet City, Awesome State` I need to split them up into separate cells for their Street, City and State.

The problem I have currently is storing the Street,City and State. I've tried something along the lines..

```
Dim addressArray() As String

posRow = 1
Do
posRow = posRow + 1
    addressFromCell= Sheet1.Cells(posRow , "C")
    addressArray() = Split(addressFromCell, ",")
        Sheet2.Cells(posRow , "A") = addressArray(0)
        Sheet2.Cells(posRow , "B") = addressArray(1)
        Sheet2.Cells(posRow , "C") = addressArray(2)
Loop Until posRow = 15
```

I thought `addressArray` would look like `{"1111 Really Cool Street","Sweet City", "Awesome State"}` and I could simply pass in the element I wanted. Instead I keep on getting

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: There's exactly one reason for this error, which is that you're going outside the array dimensions. Use the debugger to step through the code and figure out where your mistake is located. With 15 addresses, you could step through every line until the error happens in a couple of minutes time (probably much less time than you spent writing your question here).

Answer (score 3):

As Ken White pointed out, the reason for the error is that one of the values doesn't contain 2 commas.

Here is how I would do it:

```
Dim addressArray() As String

posRow = 1
Do
    posRow = posRow + 1
    addressArray() = Split(Sheet1.Cells(posRow, "C").Value, ",")
    Sheet2.Cells(posRow, "A").Resize(1, UBound(addressArray) + 1).Value = addressArray()
Loop Until posRow = 15
```

This code uses the [`UBound` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function) to retrieve the Upper Bound (number of the last element) for the Array and ensures that the Range is always the same size as the Array.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any such error, you should check if the cell is not blank and the address in the cell is not the complete address.

```
posRow = 1
Do
posRow = posRow + 1
    addressFromCell = Sheet1.Cells(posRow, "C")
    If addressFromCell <> "" Then
        addressArray() = Split(addressFromCell, ",")
        If UBound(addressArray) = 2 Then
            Sheet2.Cells(posRow, "A") = addressArray(0)
            Sheet2.Cells(posRow, "B") = addressArray(1)
            Sheet2.Cells(posRow, "C") = addressArray(2)
        End If
    End If
Loop Until posRow = 15
```

Comment: This skips incorrectly formatted addresses … but could use: If (UBound(addressArray) - LBound(addressArray) + 1) = 3 Then … to handle either Option Base 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vArray
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim s, e
    's = Timer
    vDB = Range("c2", "c15")
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To r
        vArray = Split(vDB(i, 1), ",")
        k = UBound(vArray)
        If k > 0 And k < 3 Then
            For j = 1 To k
                vR(i, j) = vArray(j - 1)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    With Sheet2
        .Range("a2").Resize(r, 3) = vR
    End With
    'e = Timer
    'Debug.Print "Test() time : " & (e - s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this code still has an issue if the address doesn't have 3 components (because of the for j = 1 to 3) … which is the reasons for subscript out of range issue?

Comment: @TechnoDabbler, op said there are 3 components.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler, It is now implemented with 14 lines of data, but if you have more than 10,000 lines of data, your code will be very slow.

Comment: Yes … but we're assuming that isn't the case because of the subscript out of range error … hence either skipping lines where this isn't the case in sktneer's answer or managing it dynamically in TinMan's answer.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler, You are right. I misunderstand op's problem.